# Determine Span of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I did not see question like this before?

What is span of $(1,1+x,1+x+x^2,....,1+x+x^2+...+x^n)$ ?

The question also says to let $V=P_n(X)$ be the space of all polynomials whose degrees are less than or equal to n"

Comment: What happens if you take a linear combination of all of those polynomials?

Comment: Are you sure $\,V\,$ is the space "of all polynomials" or, perhaps, the space of all polynomials of degree up to $\,n\,$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry I forgot to write that "be the space of all pol. whose degrees are less than or equal to n"

Comment: Then edit your question accordingly, @user71653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but if you want to show that $(p_0,\ldots,p_n) = (1,1+x,1+x+x^2,\ldots,1+x+\ldots+x^n)$ is a basis for the vector space of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ (over some field), it may help to use that $(1,x,...,x^n)$ is a basis for this vector space. And miraculously, $p_{i+1}-p_i=x^{i+1}$. So every element of this basis is in there and you can't get anything of degree $> n$.

Comment: Thanks for your ınterest but I dont think so it is the right answer because question say that "determine"

Comment: Use, I think that was a correct and accurate *hint*: show your set of polynomials contain the standard basis of $\,P_n\,$ and thus...voila! Of course, another way could be to show directly your set of vectors is linearly independent...